# Are "did X ever happen" questions appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

Example: I remember hearing about a 2-man scientific team trapped in a research vessel at the bottom of the ocean (shallow water, several hundred feet down) that ascended to the surface without additional oxygen. Supposedly they could do this because the air in their lungs at the  high pressure they started at was compressed, and continued to expand as they rose, allowing them to ascend a long distance without extra air.

Is this question (and others like it) appropriate for skeptics.se? It has a scientific bent - that is, is it possible for someone to ascend like this, and how do they avoid the bends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, all questions should be about notable claims. If the claim is notable (and thus if you can produce something more than a recollection) then you are going to be fine :-)

Comment: That's the main problem - I can't find the actual incident. That's what I was hoping for - identification of the incident. Where (if anywhere) on SE would this be on-topic? (Sort of like incident-identification, like SciFi's story-identification tag)

Comment: I would argue: off-topic

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would this be on-topic anywhere on stackexchange?

Comment: Maybe history, but it doesn't seem to be a historical event...